# Stack bootstrap columns vertically and horizontally next to each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show my columns like this

[image]

### Code

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="id-orders-stats" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 stats-box">
    <div id="id-time-tab">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified nav-prima">
        <li><a href="#" type="Daily" class="agraphType" data-toggle="tab">Daily</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" type="Weekly" class="agraphType" data-toggle="tab">Weekly</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" type="Monthly" class="agraphType" data-toggle="tab">Monthly</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="agraphType" type="Quarterly" data-toggle="tab">Quarterly</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" type="Yearly" class="agraphType" data-toggle="tab">Yearly</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="id-sales-pie">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div id="id-channel-stats" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 stats-box ">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 stats-box">
    <div id="id-sales-line">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do i achieve this?

[image]

I have looked at javascript solutions and a css solution as well but it isn't working. Kindly help

Comment: What do you mean by "this"? The way the colums are styled? The pie-chart? the border on the columns?...Otherwise it's just a pretty straight layout with two columns, each 50% width. The rows take the height of the biggest element giving it that layout.

Comment: i want to shift the column 3 above its aligned to the 4th column

Comment: I updated the fiddle, please check if that is what you mean.

Comment: _(\*A lot of ads in your image link..)_

Comment: have you considered using something like http://gridster.net/

Comment: @5ervant which ads i can't see any?

Comment: downvoters kindly specify a reason for down voting

Comment: @vini http://postimg.org/image/c2m2813vf/

Comment: oh i have ad blocker added so can't see the ads will upload it elsewhere

Comment: @vini I want to help and that image link won't help.. Can you show me a working JSFiddle and the things that you want to achieved?

Comment: This is just a lazy question. Bootstrap offers solution right out the box and you are not even reading the little documentation it comes with.

Comment: yup solved it myself.. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. Bootstrap works with a grid that is divided in 12. You want your first column to be half of the page, that means you do it like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-6"></div>
```

The other two items both take up a quarter of the page, so you add the class:

```
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```

You can find all of this on the [Bootstrap homepage](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).
Here's a fiddle for your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/zkreewdt/

**Edit** By bundeling the first two divs (1 and 2) in a row it means that the row will take the height of the biggest element and that the row beneath it will be automaticly aligned.  I updated the fiddle. please check it

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1 - Container element:** The #3 and #4 widgets are in a separate row from the #1 and #2 widgets. The css for the `.row` class will clear the floats from the previous row creating the whitespace that you are observing.

**Solution:** Place all your widgets in the same containing element.

---

**Problem 2 - Floats:** You are likely to still have vertical whitespace issues due to the variable heights of your widgets and the way the floats are rendered in the document flow.

**Solution 1:** Use [CSS Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) and have your widget pairs re-flow vertically

**Solution 2:** Use Javascript to layout your widgets. Something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html).